# Keep-Alive timeout in Apache CXF

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel, cxf, httpurlconnection

I'm using Apache CXF 3.0.6 and Java 8

I know that CXF relies on HttpURLConnection - http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html

I want to achieve http connection persistent on CXF endpoint, so i defined system property  http.maxConnections = 20, and keep-alive as true,

max connection works as expected and so as keep-alive, but the keep-alive times out within 5seconds, and then new socket is created to serve another request.

Is there any way to increase keep-alive **timeout** or is there any way to set  **MaxKeepAliveRequests** so that the socket will remain ESTABLISHED to serve request during this timeout ?

as HttpURLConnection doesn't have any method to set keep-alive timeout !

Comment: Did you try setting the connectionTimeout?

Comment: Did u get answer for this. I am also facing the same. please let me know if you find solution for this. thansk

Answer (score 0):

There is, but only in Java 19 and higher.  If you can upgrade from Java 8 to Java 19, you can do this, to set the keep-alive time to 3 minutes:

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive.time.server", "180");
```